# Spring boot application not starting with kafka and restcontroller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-restcontroller

I was having a spring-boot application which was running fine until I included Kafka consumer and producer in my application. The code which ran absolutely without issue was having a restController as shown below:

```
@RestController
public class OrderResource {
    //Get orderheaderkeys for a particular date
    //OrderLine
    @GetMapping("/orderForDate/{forDate}")
    public List<String> findOrderHeaderKeys(@PathVariable String forDate) {
        //Some business logic
        return keys;
    }
}
```

This rest end point was giving desired response. 
Now, I included kafka producer and consumer which look

```
@Component
public class KafkaProducerClient {
private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KafkaProducerClient.class);
    private KafkaProducer<String, String> producer;

    @Value("${kafka.bootstrap.servers}")
    private String kafkaBootstrapServers;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaBootstrapServers);
        properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
        properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
        producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(properties);
    }

    public void sendMessageAsync(String topic, String key, String jsonString) {
        logger.info("Sending message async to kafka topic with key = {}", key);
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        ProducerRecord<String, String> record = new ProducerRecord<>(topic, key, jsonString);

        producer.send(record, new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(RecordMetadata recordMetadata, Exception exception) {
                final long timeTaken = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
                if (recordMetadata != null) {
                    logger.info("Producer sent record(key={}, value={}). " +
                                    "Topic={}, Partition={}, Offset={}, timeTaken={}",
                            record.key(), record.value(), topic, recordMetadata.partition(),
                            recordMetadata.offset(), String.valueOf(timeTaken));
                }
                if (exception != null) {
                    logger.error("Exception occurred while posting message", exception.getMessage());
                    return;
                }
            }
        });
        logger.info("Message sent to kafka topic with key = {}", key);
    }

    public void sendMessageSync(String topic, String key, String jsonString) {
        try {
            logger.info("Sending message sync to kafka topic={} with key={}", topic, key);
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            ProducerRecord<String, String> record = new ProducerRecord<String, String>(topic, key, jsonString);
            Future<RecordMetadata> future = producer.send(record);
            producer.flush();
            RecordMetadata recordMetadata = future.get();
            final long timeTaken = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
            if (recordMetadata != null) {
                logger.info(
                        "Producer sent message by sendMessageSync. record={}. timeTaken={}",
                        recordMetadata,
                        String.valueOf(timeTaken));
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error("Exception occured....", ex);
        }

    }

    @PreDestroy
    private void shutdown(){
        producer.close();
    }
}
```

```
@Component
public class KafkaConsumerClient {
private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KafkaConsumerClient.class);
    private KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer;

    @Value("${kafka.bootstrap.servers}")
    private String kafkaBootstrapServers;

    @Value("${kafka.topic}")
    private String topic;

    @Value("${zookeeper.groupId}")
    private String groupId;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaBootstrapServers);
        properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
        properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
        properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
        consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, String>(properties);
        consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList(topic));

        while (true) {
            ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(100));
            for (ConsumerRecord record : records) {
                try {
                    logger.info("Key: " + record.key() + ", Value: " + record.value());
                    //orderResource.saveOrderToSecondaryStore(record.value().toString());
                }catch (Exception e){
                    logger.error("Exception while processing Kafka message", e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After including these consumer and producer my application does not start. I do not see the following lines which was getting displayed previously when application was running fine.

**2019-12-12 15:01:12.090  INFO 38376 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2019-12-12 15:01:12.093  INFO 38376 --- [  restartedMain] c.w.c.o.p.MySpringApplication  : Started MySpringApplication in 15.187 seconds (JVM running for 15.617)**

Comment: could you add the full log as well

Comment: Is your Kafka server up and running with the required topic?

Comment: Is there a reason not to use Spring-Kafka?

Comment: @SandeepKumar yes Kafka server up and running with the required topic.

Comment: @Fateh there is no exception in the full log, so I did not add as it was verbose with mostly Kafka producer and consumer related details.

Comment: @cricket_007 no reason as such. Just that I do not see any issue with this code, so thought I may have overlooked something.

Comment: Well, it's hard to tell where your controller uses the kafka client

Answer (score 1):

Deploying Spring Boot Application on Tomcat Server : 
update pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

update main app class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

And Update the kafka dependency and configuration also for more details follow below link - https://www.confluent.io/blog/apache-kafka-spring-boot-application/

Comment: Singh, thanks for replying. All the things you mentioned were already taken care of. The issue was because of the way kafka consumer polling was getting started as updated above and not related to configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by moving the consumer polling (the while loop) **outside the init method of KafkaConsumerClient**

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
}
```